# Doctrine2 - dynamically add "andWhere" and set Parameter

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Please, is there any way how to dynamically add "andWhere" with setting parameter? 
I want to build query which select rows from database by parameters but I don´t know number of parameters, so I need to do it dynamically. 
I tried to wrote a code bellow but it returns no result.

```
    $parametersRepository = $this
        ->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('AcmeEntityBundle:Parameter');      
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

    $q = 
    $qb
    ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC');
    $p = 0;
    $par = array();
    foreach ($associations as $parameter => $value){
        if($value != NULL){ 
        $par[$p] = $parametersRepository->find($value);
            $qb->andWhere(':parameter'.$p.' MEMBER OF p.parameters')
            ->setParameter('parameter'.$p, $par[$p]);
        $p++;
        }
    }
    $qb->getResult();
    return $q;
```

Comment: $qb->getQuery()->getResult().  I suspect you have your errors being suppressed.  Return $q make no sense in this case.

Comment: Oh, I´m and idiot :D Thank you very much!